# Why conditionals in macros does not work in IOS for idioms?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-interface

I want to write an universal app for iPhone 4, iPhone 5 and iPads.

First I developed code for iPad. Now I want to port it to other devices.

I wrote that code at the tope of the file. When I debug, I see that it never goes to second condition. It always takes the values for IS_IPAD condition although device is iPhone4.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)
#ifdef IS_IPAD
#define CELL_WIDTH 180
#define CELL_HEIGHT 123
#define CONTAINER_WIDTH 950
#define NUM_OF_ITEMS_IN_ROW 4
#define CONTAINER_LEFT_MARGIN 50
#define CONTAINER_TOP_MARGIN 70
#define CONTAINER_OUTER_TOP_MARGIN 0
#define CONTAINER_OUTER_LEFT_MARGIN 0
#define CELL_PADDING_RIGHT 32
#define CELL_PADDING_BOTTOM 20
#define MIN_CONTAINER_HEIGHT 450
#elif IS_IPHONE_4
#define IPAD_TO_IPHONE4 0.3
#define CELL_WIDTH 180 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define CELL_HEIGHT 123 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define CONTAINER_WIDTH 950 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define NUM_OF_ITEMS_IN_ROW 4
#define CONTAINER_LEFT_MARGIN 50 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define CONTAINER_TOP_MARGIN (70 * 0.3)
#define CONTAINER_OUTER_TOP_MARGIN 0 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define CONTAINER_OUTER_LEFT_MARGIN 0 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define CELL_PADDING_RIGHT 32 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define CELL_PADDING_BOTTOM 20 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#define MIN_CONTAINER_HEIGHT 450 * IPAD_TO_IPHONE4
#endif
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Change `#ifdef IS_IPAD` to `#if IS_IPAD` - you want to test the *value*, not whether it is defined (which it always is).

Comment: I see. But if I write like you said, for instance MIN_CONTAINER_HEIGHT is not seen in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with compile-time checks here. When the preprocessor gets to this line

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Afterward, `IS_IPAD` is **always** defined. What this does is tell the preprocessor that any time it sees `IS_IPAD` in code, it should replace that with `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`. *It does not execute that code*, it just replaces one piece of text with another piece of text.

That's fine for a **run time** check, meaning you could do something like this in code:

```
if (IS_IPAD) {
    ...do something iPad-specific
}
```

But preprocessor checks like `#if IS_IPAD` and `#ifdef IS_IPAD` are **always** true because`#if` and `#ifdef` are preprocessor checks that happen before the code is even compiled-- that is, they run on your Mac, during compilation, not on your device when the app is running.